# Why isn't my if statement printing anything in python?

Tags: python

I have to loop through data including 'visit_counts' affiliated with a 'city'

I made an if statement in a for loop; it doesn't give any errors but it's also not printing what I want. What I want to do: When the city == 'West Lafayette', calculate the sum of the visit that have West Lafayette as their city.

```
for v in visits_19['city']:
    if v == 'West Lafayette':
        wl_sum = visits_19['raw_visit_counts'].sum()
        print(wl_sum)
    elif v == 'Lafayette':
        l_sum = visits_19['raw_visit_counts'].sum()
        print(l_sum)
    elif v == 'Dayton':
        d_sum = visits_19['raw_visit_counts'].sum()
        print(d_sum)
    elif v == 'Batle Ground':
        bg_sum = visits_19['raw_visit_counts'].sum()
        print(bg_sum)
```

Here is an example:

```
visit_19 = {'city': ['West Lafayette','Lafayette','Lafayette','West Lafayette','West Lafayette','Dayton'],
         'visit_counts' : [100,10,151,20,2,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(visit_19)
g = df['city']

for g in df['city']:
    if g == 'West Lafayette':
        wl_sum = df['visit_counts'].sum()
        print(wl_sum)
    elif g == 'Lafayette':
        l_sum = df['visit_counts'].sum()
        print(l_sum)
    elif g == 'Dayton':
        d_sum = df['visit_counts'].sum()
        print(d_sum)
```

Right now, I don't think it is stopping/recognizing any of the conditions. I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

**UPDATE:
I'm kind of new to python and wasn't aware of the built-in .groupby() function. I worked with it as mentioned in some of the comments and that did the trick for what I wanted to see! Thanks for all the help.**

Comment: `for v in visits_19` loops through the *keys* of your dictionary, i.e. `'city'` and `'visit_counts'`.

Comment: Did you mean `for g in df['city']`?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: All `if..elif` do the exact same thing. You'll get the same output for every city once you fix it using tobias's suggestion

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in `.groupby()` to get grouped sums?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69470998/if-statement-is-not-printing-anything-in-python Please don't reask your question (especially when you haven't done any debugging based on the comments you received the first time). Instead, edit it and it'll go to the reopen queue.

Comment: One thing that will help you understand what's happening, add `print(g)` in your loop and you'll see what `for g in df:` is actually iterating over

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Oh sorry! I'm new to stack overflow, I did edit it and asked questions in the other one but for some reason nothing updated and it wasn't notifying me about any other comments.

Comment: @Barmar Good suggestion! I'm kind of new to python. I'll be sure to check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. Seems like you need something along this line

```
for something in g:
    if something == 'West Lafayette':
        wl_sum = df['visit_counts'].sum()
        print(wl_sum)
    elif something == 'Lafayette':
        l_sum = df['visit_counts'].sum()
        print(l_sum)
    elif something == 'Dayton':
        d_sum = df['visit_counts'].sum()
        print(d_sum)
```

And this is probably the answer to your actual question

```
df.groupby(['city']).sum()
```

Comment: how does this differ from OP's code at all?

Comment: I thought OP was trying to loop through g which was assigned to df['city']

Comment: @Mahbub yes, thank you! I meant to loop through g and I'm kind of new to python so I wasn't aware of .groupby yet. That did the trick. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are not interating over the values, you are only iterating over the keys.  You need the values...

```
visit_19 = {'city': ['West Lafayette','Lafayette','Lafayette','West Lafayette','West Lafayette','Dayton'],
         'visit_counts' : [100,10,151,20,2,5]}

x = zip(visit_19['city'], visit_19['visit_counts'])
result = {'raw_visits':0}
for c,v in x:
    if c in result:
        result[c] += v
    else:
        result[c] = v
    result['raw_visits'] += v

print(result)
```

Comment: you don't need to convert `x` to list to iterate over, just use `for c, v in x:`

Comment: @eatmeimadanish Thanks! It worked like a charm! Also yes, turns out you don't need to convert it to a list for it to work

Comment: @Matiiss I did try, and though it happened on my first attempt it worked when I went back and changed it.  Thanks for the correction.